# Is it possible to remove the full-paths from .NET assemblies created with dotnet build?

Tags: c#, .net-core, f#, msbuild

I build my project with `dotnet build`, targeting `netcoreapp3.1`.

The problem is that the assemblies contain the full path to the source-files:

```
/home/runner/my-app/App.fs
```

This means that the hash of the assemblies depends on the directory where the code was built. I want it to only depend on the hash of the source-files and the .NET SDK itself.

Is there a way to make `dotnet build` use relative paths like this?

```
./my-app/App.fs
```

Comment: What is the C# question here? The file seems to be F#...

Comment: Well `dotnet build` is how most C# code gets built. The question is agnostic to the .NET langauge.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can configure a release build with less information or you can override [PathMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019#PathMap) value to override it.

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Override Stack trace file locations">
  <PathMap>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)'))=./</PathMap>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The following `Directory.Build.props` in the root of the project should work:

```xml
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <DeterministicSourcePaths>true</DeterministicSourcePaths>
    <PathMap>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)'))=./</PathMap>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks @cdev Is there any easy way to set the `PathMap` base to be the project root since I have multiple projects in subfolders?

Comment: interesting, I never wanted that before. Let me have a look.

Comment: this does it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019

Comment: It's pretty crucial if you have continuous deployment, I'm surprised that no one else has asked this before!

Comment: your main question or second one?

Comment: The main question

Comment: yeah. you can consider that as feature also, so you have more information. But ultimately missing a best practice.

Comment: cdev and @sdgfsdh: When I try this (linux, dotnet5, vscode) I can't debug (every debugging sessions fails with error: `Could not load source './Program.cs': Incorrect format of 'source' message..`). When you use these settings, can you still debug your project?

Comment: @Ionix I have not run into that, perhaps the `PropertyGroup` could be conditional on being a Release build?

Comment: @ionix, I tried in docker linux .net core 5. haven't get this issue.

Comment: Maybe `ContinuousIntegrationBuild` would be interesting too [Deterministic Builds CI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/producing-packages-with-source-link/#deterministic-builds)

Answer (score 5):

C# compiler (csc) has a compiler switch [`-deterministic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/deterministic-compiler-option)

F# compiler (fsc) appears to have a switch [`--deterministic+`](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/pull/2954)

From looking at the DotNet SDK repo it appears there are 2 properties for project files:

```
<Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
<DeterministicSourcePaths>true</DeterministicSourcePaths>
```

You might not need both of these.

Comment: Thanks. What is a good way to add these switches via `fsproj` and `csproj` files?

Comment: Added some ideas

Comment: Are these project properties documented anywhere? (I have searched)

Comment: These do not remove the full paths

Answer (score 2):

I can find no reason not to prefer either

```xml
<DeterministicSourcePaths>true</DeterministicSourcePaths>
```

where the SDK supports it, or

```xml
<PathMap>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)=./</PathMap>
```

over

```xml
<PathMap>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)'))=./</PathMap>
```

However, there may be reason not to use `MSBuildThisFileDirectory` at all and this is not explained or demonstrated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties).

---

When used in `Directory.Build.props` the `MSBuildThisFileDirectory` property points to the directory of `Directory.Build.props`, not the project it applies to. This makes

```xml
<PathMap>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)=./</PathMap>
```

behave semantically the same whether used in `Directory.Build.props` in a directory above (below) a `.csproj` file but possibly not in the desired way. In comparison the `MSBuildProjectDirectory` property always points to the `.csproj` directory.

### Demonstration

Suppose a tree like

```
foo/
├── foo.sln
├── Directory.Build.props
├── FooMain/
│   ├── FooMain.csproj
│   └── src/
│       └── Foo.cs
└── FooTest/
    ├── FooTest.csproj
    └── src/
        └── Foo.cs
```

This table shows how different values for `PathMap` set in different places affect the outcome of throwing an exception from `FooMain/src/Foo.cs`; in particular, it shows that only `MSBuildProjectDirectory` is independent of its placement:

| `PathMap` value | Where | Sample stack trace path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)=./` | `Directory.Build.props` | `./FooMain/src/Foo.cs:line 42` |
| `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)=./` | `*.csproj` | `./src/Foo.cs:line 42` |
| `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)=./` | `Directory.Build.props` | `./src/Foo.cs:line 42` |
| `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)=./` | `*.csproj` | `./src/Foo.cs:line 42` |
| `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)=./$(MSBuildProjectName)/` | `Directory.Build.props` | `./FooMain/src/Foo.cs:line 42` |
| `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)=./$(MSBuildProjectName)/` | `*.csproj` | `./FooMain/src/Foo.cs:line 42` |

Instead of using `PathMap` directly, supported SDKs contemporary with the recently released .NET 7 offer the `DeterministicSourcePaths` option. When configured with

```xml
<DeterministicSourcePaths>true</DeterministicSourcePaths>
```

it behaves with the same consistency as

```xml
<PathMap>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)=./$(MSBuildProjectName)/</PathMap>
```

but the sample stack trace path becomes `/_/FooMain/src/Foo.cs:line 42`.

To work reliably, though `DeterministicSourcePaths` also requires adding

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <SourceRoot Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

to the root `Directory.Build.props`.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties
- https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/37379
- [Get source file location with DeterministicSourcePaths turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67744586/482758)

---

Whichever option you use, consider that while isolating the stack trace paths is certainly necessary for build reproducibility (despite not being mentioned in the `DotNet.ReproducibleBuilds` package as of version 1.1.1) there may be tools that expect to be able to read the absolute path from the stack traces. In particular, it may be practically infeasible to enable deterministic paths for test projects.