# Get source file location with DeterministicSourcePaths turned on

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, deterministic

**Question:**
Is there a way how to get the Caller or current frame source code location without using the `CallerFilePath` attribute?

**Background:**

I have this helper defined:

```
public class PathHelper
{
    public static string GetThisFilePath([CallerFilePath] string path = null)
    {
        return path;
    }
}
```

That can be called as follows to obtain the location of source code used to build the binary:

```
var currentSourceFilePath = PathHelper.GetThisFilePath();
```

This works fine, unless I have [DeterministicSourcePaths](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/blob/main/docs/README.md#deterministicsourcepaths) turned on (typically via ContinuousIntegrationBuild msbuild property). In such a case the returned paths are trimmed to something like:

```
/_/MyRelativeSourcePath
```

So it seems that determinist paths are injected into the compiler functionality supporting `CallerFilePath` yielding this behavior.

I need the source code location in order to be able to unit test product specific functionality (that has to do with inspecting build process), while I'd still like to support fully determinisitc build on CI machines.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like following. Please note

- this is just an idea, exact implementation depends on your environment
- This would be working if you are using "default build output paths" only
- I didn't tested it

  ```
    public static string GetThisFilePath([CallerFilePath] string path = null)
    {
        const string determenisticRoot = "/_/";

        if(!path.StartsWith(determenisticRoot))
        {
            return path;
        }

        // callerBinPath would be something like $(SolutionRoot)/.../MyProject.Tests/bin/Debug/net5.0
        var callerBinPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location);

        // Traverse to $(TestProjectRoot) - testProjectRoot would be something like $(SolutionRoot)/.../MyProject.Tests
        var testProjectRoot = Path.Combine(callerExecutablePath, "../../..");

        // Combine projectRoot root with relative path from [CallerFilePath]
        return Path.Combine(testProjectRoot, path.Substring(determenisticRoot.Length));
    }
  ```

Comment: Thanks @Vladyslav for the idea. Unfortunately it might give an impression of working solution while being quite fragile. For now I ended up disabling deterministic source paths on all test code - giving me workaround for my scenario. Would that be a production code, one should probably rething/redesign not to need the build time code paths during the runtime.